# How to get the repartition of date point javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, statistics, fft

I have an array with dates inside. The dates are not uniformaly spreaded over time. I'm searching for an algorithm that helps me getting the different harmonics of it.

I mean, I have for instance an array over 10 years. In the array, I can visually see groups of dates during the winters and less during summers (whatever the exact dates). I'd like an algorithm that returns **best step: 1 year**

Seems like fourrier transform?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Show some effort!

Comment: How do you define “best step”? One approach might be to compute the time elapsed between each consecutive timestamp and view its histogram—then the peak/mode of the histogram (if it has one) could be interpreted as a “best step”, but it depends on what you need the “best step” to do.